# Play template don't evaluates a variable starting with @

Tags: templates, scala, playframework

Hello I will start by presenting my code.

```
@defining("addPostForm"){formId =>
@main("Add a blog post.") {
    <h1>Add a blog post</h1>

    @errors

    @form(routes.Application.addPost, 'id -> "@formId") {
        @inputText(name = "content", required = true)
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#@formId").validator();
    </script> 
}
}
```

Why is it that the @fromId in the @form won't be evaluated by play? This is a snippet of the generated html page.

```
<form action="/addPost" method="POST" id="@formId">
```

But later in the page it is working fine as this is generated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addPostForm").validator();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does not work because you already in a Scala code section, try this :

```
    @form(routes.Application.addPost, 'id -> formId)
```

The later code is not included in a code section, so it works as expected.

Comment: That was my first attempt but sadly that won't compile. ')' expected but '@' found.

Comment: I edited the answer, try this :  `@form(routes.Application.addPost,("id", formId)) {`

Comment: Thanks for the "Symbol", I edited the answer for further readers ;-)

Comment: :) I just got an aha moment it was just to remove the @ all along. This works fine @form(routes.Application.addPost, 'id -> formId)